# Radio within a Radio Button

Tags: visualforce

I am displaying radio button is visualforce page.I have a requirement where when i click a radio button value it has populate it child radio buttons under it.
i.e in the following way

```
fruits
  Apple
  Mango
  orange
Vegetables
  potato
  tomato
```

So from the above example initially it has to display fruits and vegetables when i click on fruits(Apple,Mango,Orange) have to display and when vegetable is selected (Potato,tomato) have to be displayed

Comment: Have to tried using Dependent picklist, I mean create 2 picklists  1) One for Fruit,Vegetable,etc   and another 2) for Mango,Apple,tommatto,potato, etc.     --- Add dependency accordingly. And then Use them in VF page like radio button

Comment: Hey i checked It is not possible displaying dependent pick list values as radio buttons

Answer (score 5):

Try this code !

----Visualforce Page-----

```
<apex:page controller="dependRadioCont">
 <apex:form >
  <apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedItem}">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!Items}"></apex:selectOptions>
   <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!getchange}"/>
  </apex:selectRadio>

  <apex:selectRadio rendered="{!radioFruits}">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!Fruits}"></apex:selectOptions>
  </apex:selectRadio>

  <apex:selectRadio rendered="{!radioVeg}">
   <apex:selectOptions value="{!Veg}"></apex:selectOptions>
  </apex:selectRadio>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

------Controller------

```
public class dependRadioCont 
{
  public String selectedItem {get;set;}
  public Boolean radioFruits {get;set;}
  public Boolean radioVeg {get;set;}

  public dependRadioCont()
  {
  radioFruits = false;
  radioVeg = false;
  }

  public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Fruits','Fruits')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Veg','Veg')); 
        return options; 
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getFruits() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Apple','Apple')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Orange','Orange')); 
        return options; 
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getVeg() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Potato','Potato')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('Tomato','Tomato')); 
        return options; 
    }

    public void getchange()
    {
     if(selectedItem == 'Fruits')
     {
     radioFruits = true;
     radioVeg = false;
     }
     else
     {
     radioVeg = true;
     radioFruits = false; 
     }

    }

}
```

And mark it as answer if it helped.